# is $.ajax() jQuery's way of shortening the normal code: function loadXMLDoc() { var xmlhttp; if (window.XMLHttpRequest)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So as my question asked: is $.ajax() jQuery's way of shortening the normal code
(These are both different examples, because my question is just regarding the structure)
is

```
  $.ajax(
        {url:"index.php/a", 
        type:"POST",
        contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data:{some_string:"blabla"},
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data){
            alert(data);
            },
        error:function(a,b,c){
            }
        });
```

the same as

```
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly the same, but yes it's basically serving the same purpose. (there are significant differences between the functionality of the two examples though, not least of which is that one is sending a POST request and the other a GET request)

I would suggest taking a look at the (uncompressed) source code for jQuery to see what the `$.ajax()` function does. It is quite a lot more complex than your raw `XMLHttpRequest` code, but yes it does do basically the same job, and at the core of it, it does call the same `XMLHttpRequest` class.